# setting the font for a screen in a WPF application

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to set a font for a screen in wpf. I mean if i am able to set a font property to Tahoma,  all the text[including user controls] displayed in that particular screen uses the font Tahoma. Right now i am manually changing the fonts of all the text elements.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you set the `FontFamily` of a Window to Tahoma, the text in the majority of controls shoud use that font because of property value inheritance. For example `Button` and `TextBlock` should do that.

Anyway there are few controls such as `StatusBar`, `Menu`, and `ToolTip` that set internally their font type to the font system setting (which the user can change with the Window Control Panel). As a consequence these elements will ignore the font settings in the window.

Answer (score 0):

The Window is a Control from which it derives the FontFamily-property. By inheritance all the font family is set on all underlying Controls.

I think you need to consider using WPF-Styles, for example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Showcard Gothic"/>
</Style>
```

will set all Buttons to this font family based on which scope (Window or Application, for instance) you define your resources.